# Check the file whether is it by another process

Tags: vb.net

I have some ask to you to check and advice if my code is enough and correct. My application works on files sometimes its downloading multiple files by windows service and then by other windows service parser process those files are parsing. Unfortunately before process file has to be finished downloading before process parser should open the file and play with it therefore i prepared some code to check firstly whether the file is free - means not open by another process or some person, whatever. I use most cases streamreader to open the file and play with it but as i said i would like firstly check file if its ready.

This is my code, what do you think:

```
Public Shared Function FileInUse(ByVal sFile As String, ByVal log As String) As Boolean

        Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = True
        Dim counter As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To 30
            counter += 1
            If System.IO.File.Exists(sFile) Then
                Try
                    Using f As New IO.FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
                        thisFileInUse = False
                        Exit For
                    End Using
                Catch
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)        '10 sec
                End Try
            End If
        Next

        Return thisFileInUse

    End Function
```

Comment: Can you make the services talk to each other, so the processing service can know when the downloading service has actually finished downloading before then processing?  Alternatively, have a look at the [`IFileIsInUse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775874.aspx) interface.

Comment: how to achieve that if my windows services are running separatly

Comment: You could connect them to each other using a named pipe or socket, for instance. Or, using `IFileIsInUse`, it goes into the Running Object Table, which is globally accessible by multiple processes so they can share objects with each other.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your sugestion, i read about that and its seems intresting for me and to my issue, do you know such cain of nice tutorial how to implement it - i chceked over google but didnt find any nice one.